# IVP with boundary condition (incorrect statement)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, initial-value-problems

Suppose, I would like to solve initial value problem (IVP)
$$
(1):\quad
\begin{cases}
x'(t)=f_1(t,x,y),\\
y'(t)=f_2(t,x,y),
\end{cases}
$$
with initial conditions 
$$
(2):\quad
x(0)=x_0,y(0)=y_0
$$ 
and $t\in[t_1,\,t_2]$, but at the same time ''from physics'' is known that there is a constraint
$$
(3):\qquad\qquad\left.y'(t)\right|_{t=t_2}=0.
$$

Is there any chance to join eqns. $(1)-(3)$ and solve them numerically anyhow?

**Update 1**

According to request of **@Rebellos** let me briefly explain motivation and write exact equations.

Exact system was introduced [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/100259/comparison-between-numerical-solution-of-nonlinear-ode-and-nonlinear-ode-of-seco) earlier and may come from more general system in the following form
$$
(4):\quad
\begin{cases}
\partial_x E(x,t) = 1 - n_e(x,t),\\
\partial_x n_e(x,t) = -8E(x,t)n_e(x,t).
\end{cases}
$$
I considered (4) in every moment of time $\forall t$ as a nonlinear system of ode's in space $x\in[0,\,L]$ 
$$
(5):\quad
\begin{cases}
E'(x) = 1 - n_e(x),\\
n'_e(x) = -8E(x)n_e(x).
\end{cases}
$$
with initial condition
$$
(6a):\quad
E(0)=E_0,~n_e(0)=n_0.
$$
But, ''from physics'' is known that 
$$
(6b):\quad
\partial_x \left.E(x,t)\right|_{x=L}=0.
$$

**Q:** The issue is that how to solve numerically $(4),(6a)$ along with constraint $(6b)$.

**Update 2**

According to request of **@Lutz Lehmann**, here constans are $L,n_0,E_0=\text{const},$ space and time variables are $(x,t)\in[0,\,L]\times[0,\,T].$

*Remark 1.* Maybe (highly likely) that my question is completely incorrent and it has no sence, or maybe (probably not) somebody can classify it as ill-posed problem, for example [link](http://math.sfu-kras.ru/sites/default/files/shlapunov_jj.pdf).

*Remark 2.* I thought about the some kind of regularization like
$$
(7):\quad
\begin{cases}
\kappa\cdot\partial_t E(x,t) + \partial_x E(x,t) = 1 - n_e(x,t),\\
\kappa\cdot\partial_t E(x,t) + (n_e(x,t))^{-1}\partial_x n_e(x,t) = -8E(x,t),
\end{cases}
$$
where $\kappa$ is relatively small, let's say $\kappa\approx10^{-4}.$ Adding IC and BC
$$
(8):\quad
\left.E(x,t)\right|_{t=0}\equiv E_0,\,\left.n_e(x,t)\right|_{t=0}\equiv n_0,\,
\left.E(x,t)\right|_{x=0}\equiv E_0,\,\left.n_e(x,t)\right|_{x=0}\equiv n_0,\,
$$
it's not a big deal to solve $(7),(8)$ with Wolfram Mathematica (WM), for example $T=1$, and achieve steady-state solution as follows, and $6b$ is not satisfied in that case.
[image: Steady-state solution]

**Update 3**

More interesting comparison can be performed. Problem $(5),(6a)$ can be solved in WM directly by classical Runge-Kutta ([RK](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveDoubleStep.html)) 2nd and 4th order methods as well as problem $(7),(8),(6b)$ can be solved manually by method of lines ([MOL](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveMethodOfLines.html)). As a result, the following figure one may get
[image]

Comment: Can you typeset the equations as well, if they are exact?

Comment: @Rebellos, original post was updated.

Comment: Is $L$ fixed or also a variable of this problem?

Comment: @LutzLehmann, original post was updated.

Comment: Note that while $n_e$ and its derivative look visually as if they were constant zero, they both always will have positive values (that get ever smaller)$.